# How can I obtain objects from list with C# LINQ using boolean conditions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hello I'm making a controller through its URL you can obtain certain items from a list. If you input a letter all students in the hard coded list whos surname start with letter are shown on the webpage. But I'm struggling with the LINQ query because when using the code below I'm getting a blank page no matter what. What am I doing wrong and how can I obtain the elements I need and have them in a list?

EDIT: Lower case in URL was the issue. Thank you!

```
public IActionResult Surname(string letter)
{
    string query = letter;
    //  if(letter != null) { query = letter; }
    List<Student> studenten = new List<Student>()
    {
        new Student { Naam = "Johan", Achternaam = "Jacobs" },
        new Student { Naam = "Karel", Achternaam = "Jay" },
        new Student { Naam = "John", Achternaam = "Jas" }
    };

    List<Student> newStudents = studenten.Where(x => x.Achternaam.StartsWith(query) == true)
                                         .ToList();

    ViewData["Student"] = newStudents;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `letter` param ? It should be `j` to give to give you any results in `newStudesnts` variable.

Comment: The parameter will be input in the URL i.e.:   Controller/Index/?letter=j so its variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make use of an overload of `StartsWith` method:

```
public bool StartsWith(
    string value,
    bool ignoreCase,  // set this as true
    CultureInfo culture // set this as invariant culture
)

var newStudents = studenten.Where(x => x.Achternaam
                                         .StartsWith(
                                               query, 
                                               true,
                                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                           .ToList();
```

Doing so if your url is the following one:

```
Controller/Index/?letter=j
```

or this one:

```
Controller/Index/?letter=J
```

you would get always the results your are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the help ! But the startwith wants another argument before the ignoreCase, what should be there? It says it takes 3 arguments while I have 3 arguments

Comment: There was a problem with one more comma, unfortunately I couldn't remove the comma without changing anything more. What a pity! Sorry for removing named arguments, yet it doesn't change validity of your answer.

Comment: @DominikSzymański not a problem at all :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, your code works like a charm. However, you have to input uppercase `J` letter, as you do not check for case sensitivity.

To achieve desired results `Where` clause should look like:

```
newStudents = studenten.Where(x => x.Achternaam.ToLower().StartsWith(query.ToLower()))
```

Moreover, you could move `ToLower` to query assigning line, to make it a bit more readable like:

```
public IActionResult Surname(string letter)
{
    string query = letter.ToLower();
    List<Student> studenten = new List<Student>()
    {
        new Student { Naam = "Johan", Achternaam = "Jacobs" },
        new Student { Naam = "Karel", Achternaam = "Jay" },
        new Student { Naam = "John", Achternaam = "Jas" }
    };

    List<Student> newStudents = studenten.Where(x => x.Achternaam.ToLower().StartsWith(query)).ToList();

    ViewData["Student"] = newStudents;

    return View();
}
```

Also, `== true` part is redundant, as `StartsWith` returns boolean value (which you are comparing to, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's missing the ToLower function, because your url is like this Controller/Index/?letter=j. Try this:

```
    public IActionResult Surname(string letter)
    {
        string query = letter;
      //  if(letter != null) { query = letter; }
        List<Student> studenten = new List<Student>()
         {
          new Student { Naam = "Johan", Achternaam = "Jacobs" },
          new Student { Naam = "Karel", Achternaam = "Jay" },
          new Student { Naam = "John", Achternaam = "Jas" }
         };

        List<Student> newStudents = studenten.Where(x => x.Achternaam.ToLower().StartsWith(query.ToLower()) == true).ToList();

        ViewData["Student"] = newStudents;

        return View();
    }
```